# How to define a preprocessor macro that uses another as a conditional?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have a game that uses some common macros to figure out what device the user is on:

```
#define IS_IPAD      (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_4  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_5  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)
```

It's an older game, and I just want to use a multiplier adjust some positioning. A macro would be ideal:

```
#ifdef IS_IPHONE_6
#define SIZEMOD 1.172f
#elif IS_IPHONE_6P
#define SIZEMOD 1.6875f
#else
#define SIZEMOD 1.0f
#endif
```

Unfortunately, this checks to see if the macro `IS_IPHONE_6` is defined, which will always be true and therefore the wrong multiplier is used on other devices.  How can I properly define `SIZEMOD` using a macro?

Comment: Please stop using macros for this. Write proper function please. Inline function won't be any slower than macro but actually readable and debuggable.

Comment: This isn't a "should I use macros" question. Macros are useful. I am the only developer. I already have the macro in use throughout the code. I won't be maintaining this code or possible ever touching it again. If I do touch it again in a few years, I'd rather add another macro for that multiplier rather than go digging through source.

Comment: Well, I don't see how inline function differ that macro in terms of digging though source. And the solution of your question is don't use macro because it won't work. You simply cannot get device type in compile time. You _have to_ write a function for that.

Comment: Code that uses any of these macros is written incorrectly.  Calculations should be based on the size of the view at runtime, not some check of the device model. Code should work as-is, with no code changes, no matter what new screen sized devices become available in the future. And what about dealing with multi-tasking on an iPad? An iPad app has to deal with several possible sizes.

Comment: Honestly, some people are just fanatical about this. You don't know anything about the project. Sometimes it is okay to use macros. Not everything is a simple utility app with a minimalist UI that can stretch to infinity. Sometimes people write games that depend on relatively specific device conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I don't get downvoted to hell for this

```
#define IS_IPAD      (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_4  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_5  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6  (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)

#define (SIZEMOD IS_IPHONE_6 ? 1.172f : IS_IPHONE_6P ? 1.6875f : 1.0)
```

Comment: Ah. Didn't realize you could chain ternary operator like this.

Comment: Just a quick note - you must wrap the definition in parenthesis. Otherwise, order of operations can do some crazy things if you say something like x = y+100*SIZEMOD;

Answer (score 0):

I much better way to do this is use proper functions. Here's something I use often, which works well and supports all know iOS models.

https://github.com/duhovny/DeviceHardware